# How does matlab run this code so quickly?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this code in matlab

```
b = 0.25*ones(4)
a = [0 1 1 1 ; 1/3 0 0 0 ; 1/3 0 0 0; 1/3 0 0 0] 

m = .85*a + .15*b

v = [1/4 1/4 1/4 1/4]

m^1e308*v'
```

1. How does matlab run `m^1e308*v'` so quickly? it should mutiply the
   matrix `1e300` times, but it probably do some other calculation,
   what is it?
2. why does `m^1e309*v'` gives :

   ans =

   ```
      NaN
      NaN
      NaN
      NaN
   ```
3. how can I see what `m^inf` is without using symbolic variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does matlab run `m^1e308*v'` so quickly?

I can't tell you what the internals of Matlab are doing, but note that in general, `A^n` can be done in `O(log n)` time, not `O(n)` time.

For example, `A^16 = (((A^2)^2)^2)^2`.

You can also use the eigendecomposition to turn this into scalar powering, i.e. if `A = U*V*U'`, then the power is `U * V^N * U'`, where `V` is a diagonal matrix.

> why does `m^1e309*v'` give `NaN`?

Double-precision cannot represent `1e309`.

> how can I see what `m^inf` is without using symbolic variables?

Use the eigendecomposition described above.  If any of the eigenvalues are smaller than 1, they will go to 0, if any of them are greater than 1, they will go to infinity.

Comment: The internals of MATLAB are summarized in my answer, for what its worth.

Comment: Good call.  `help mpower` explains exactly what MATLAB does, and it's basically what you just said.  Repeated squaring for integer powers, otherwise eigendecomposition

Comment: Known as Square-And-Multiply http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring This algorithm is also used to compute `ModPow` on big integers, an operation common in cryptography.

Comment: Would you do it yourself with a minimal (or at least in `O(log n)` multiplications, you could compute `res = a^b`, with `b` integer using the binary representation of `b`, like below:
    `res = 1;
    base = a;
    expo = b;
    while expo ~= 0
        if mod(expo, 2)
            res = res * base;
        end
        expo = floor(expo / 2);
        base = base ^ 2;
    end`

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB is so fast because it uses a [Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms (BLAS) Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms). The level of optimization goes right down to the CPU level, with AMD and Intel writing optimized libraries for their architectures.

BLAS is used to build the foundation of the MATLAB (MATrix LABoratory), as BLAS was used to build [Linear Algebra Package (LAPACK)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK). LAPACK provides all the low-level matrix commands in MATLAB (such as the transpose `'` and matrix multiplication in `m = .85*a + .15*b`). It's written in FORTRAN and is open source, so what most people don't know is that MATLAB is arguably selling you convenience and a GUI.

Comment: This is true, but you're talking about implementation optimization, which always comes after algorithm optimization.  No matter how efficiently the library will multiply two matrices, you'll still never be able to do m^1e308 in the naive way.  Plus you wouldn't like the numerical error of the answer.  First, choose the smart mathematical and numerical approach.  THEN, figure out how to do it efficiently on your platform.  The answer to the second problem is usually, as you say, "use BLAS and LAPACK".

Comment: I think you are confusing my answer. I am not instructing "what to do". I'm literally just informing the OP "How MATLAB runs this code so quickly", as asked. If the OP noticed its fast, why would I even *need* to instruct him how to make it fast?

Comment: No, not confusing your answer.  I did take some liberties in pronouns and verbs, but what I was trying to imply, politely, is that there are two parts to the answer, and you're presenting the less important part.  That's not a hit, so don't take offense.  The OP should read Oli's answer first, then yours for the next level of detail.

Comment: Ok, that's fair. Though, I think the physical *title* of the question is misleading if what is "more important" was why the OP's code wasn't working as expected. For long-winded and/or confusing questions, I always try to go back and look at the title and answer that question. That's all I tried to do here.

Answer (score 2):

As others have explained, [diagonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#An_application) can be used to compute the powers of a matrix efficiently. Try it yourself:

```
[V,D] = eig(M);             %# M = V*D*inv(V)
V*(D.^realmax)/V            %# M^n = V*D^n*inv(V)
```

and compare against:

```
M^realmax                   %# same as: mpower(M,realmax)
```

---

#### EDIT:

Here is the [answer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html#f75-20868) in MathWorks own words:

> `^`
>
> Matrix power. `X^p` is `X` to the power `p`, if `p` is a scalar. If `p` is an
>   integer, the power is computed by repeated squaring. If the integer is
>   negative, `X` is inverted first. For other values of `p`, the calculation
>   involves eigenvalues and eigenvectors, such that if `[V,D] = eig(X)`,
>   then `X^p = V*D.^p/V`.
>
> If `x` is a scalar and `P` is a matrix, `x^P` is `x` raised to the matrix
>   power `P` using eigenvalues and eigenvectors. `X^P`, where `X` and `P` are
>   both matrices, is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Does the solution converge ?
After one exponent n maybe it just can see that m^n * m = m^n and so m^1e30000=m^n

It can use even an heuristic because those probability matrices (sum in each column = 1 ; each value between 0 and 1) are known to converge at infinity.

Comment: I doubt that Matlab is applying such a heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the internals of matlab, but diagonalisation might be the solution (also it might parallellize the calculation internaly?)

check this chapter: [Applications of diagonalisation](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/martin/fme4a.pdf) for details